# Why is wave-number $k$ taken real & not complex when dealing with infinite line of atoms in a lattice?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This is the following excerpt from [13–2States of definite energy](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_13.html#Ch13-S2) where Feynman tells why $k$ must be real:

> [...] Notice that we have been assuming that the number $k$ that we put in our trial solution, Eq. (13.10), was a real number. We can see now why that must be so if we have an infinite line of atoms. Suppose that $k$ were an imaginary number, say $ik′.$ Then the amplitudes an would go as $e^{k′x_n}$, which means that the amplitude would get larger and larger as we go toward large $x$’s—or toward large negative $x$’s if $k′$ is a negative number. This kind of solution would be O.K. if we were dealing with line of atoms that ended, but cannot be a physical solution for an infinite chain of atoms. It would give infinite amplitudes—and, therefore, infinite probabilities—which can’t represent a real situation.

I've few confusions in this: why did he say 'the amplitude would get larger and larger as we go toward large $x$’s'? He writes in previous para

> [...] the amplitude goes as a complex oscillation—the magnitude is **the same at every atom**, but the phase at a given time advances by the amount ($ikb$) from one atom to the next.

Even if $x$ increases, it would increase by an increment of $b$'s the width between two adjacent atoms. But this is just a phase & the magnitude that is $e^{ikx_n}$ remains smae though, as argued by Feynman. But here, it seems to me that instead of taking $e^{ikb}$ as phase, he is including it in the magnitude & thus writes 'the amplitude would get larger and larger as we go toward large $x$’s'. Why is it so? Why did Feynman say the amplitude would increase as $x$ increases when $k$ is complex, after all, the amplitude would also increase with increase in $x$ when $k$ is real, isn't it? In the case of $k$ being imaginary, he includes $e^{ikb}$ as the magnitude while he considers it only as phase with magnitude of amplitude being same at all atoms when $k$ is real. Why is it so? Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wavefunction is proportional to $\exp(ikx)$.  Suppose $k$ is complex: $k=k_r+ik_i$.  Then the exponential factor becomes $$\exp(i\,(k_r + ik_i)x)$$ or $$\exp(ik_rx)\exp(-k_ix)$$
The phase factor is still there, but the wavefunction picks up an exponential.  The exponential is infinite on one side or the other, and so the wavefunction is non-physical.

Comment: but does that mean that for a finite crystal we may take "k" to be complex?

Comment: Didn't Feynman wrongly write $e^{k'x_n}$? Wouldn't it be $e^{-k'x_n}$?

Comment: @Ari That's correct.  But the $k$ vectors in a solid have a size that's roughly the order of magnitude $1/a$ where $a$ is the lattice constant, the distance between unit cells in the solid.  That means that the wave function would become exponentially large after only several lattice constants.  For a macroscopic solid this is not an acceptable solution.  But it does become important for small structures such as thin atomic layers.  In those cases you can't declare that the wave function is strictly real.

Comment: No, Feynman is ok.  The wave function blows up either to the left or to the right depending on the sign of $k'$.   Another way to look at it is that I could just as well have written $k = k_r - ik_i$

Comment: Yours is correct; Feynman takes $k$ as $ik'$; if I replace it with $k$ in $e^{ikx_n}$, what should I get? $$e^{ikx_n}= e^{i(ik')x_n}= e^{i^2 k'x_n}= e^{-k'x_n} .$$ So, it's not giving $e^{ik'x_n}.$ There is a '$-$' sign which Feynman omitted.